# Нужна помощь по регулярным выражениям php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Пока не очень хорошо понимаю регулярное выражение php.
Прошу подсказать, как обрезать спереди ноли

примеры чисел которые есть:
000010
000210
000112
004010

Мне нужно отрезать ноли перед тем числом больше 0

а вот пример чисел которые я хочу получить:
10
210
112
4010

Comment: `echo (int)"000010"`, `+"001"`, `ltrim("001", '0')`

Comment: но если прям уж совсем невтерпеж через регулярки то `preg_replace('/^0+/', "00010")`

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать функцию `preg_replace`. В качестве параметров передаём регулярное выражение, чем заменить найденные в выражении символы и строку в которой делаем замену.

```
preg_replace('/^0+/', "", "00010")
```

`^` - ищем в начале строки
`0+` - 1 или более символов

Comment: казалось бы замену надо проводить когда не 0 и более символов, а 1 и более.

Comment: @teran согласен, квантификатор в данном случае следовало бы использовать `+` вместо `*`

Comment: Согласен, отредактировал на `+`

Answer (score 0):

Еще проще
$str = ltrim($str, '0');